# Problems with pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

[image: The following is an image with Pytesseract guessing what's on small window with '59' below in the white text]

This is an image with Pytesseract guessing what's on small window with '59' below in the white text.

The window is a live screen grab and not a static image.

[EDIT] Was advised to post the small image so people can experiment with it, so here:-

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pytesseract as loki

loki.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Users\Rahul And Anisha\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

while True:
    Odo = ImageGrab.grab(bbox = (1055,505, 1170, 570))
    
    Speed = loki.image_to_string(Odo)
    
    Odo = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(Odo), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    
    cv2.imshow('Speed' , Odo)
    
    print(Speed)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

The problem is that no matter what config I set (Tried --psm1 through --psm13), tesseract is unable to guess the number correctly

What's the problem here?

Comment: Try negative image, try giving some padding. Maybe post the small image, so somebody can experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a little bit of empty area around the text(padding). The below code is for the smaller image.

```
    M = np.float32([[1,0,25],[0,1,25]])
    img = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols*2,rows*2),borderValue=(127,127,127))
    custom_oem_psm_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=1234567890'
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img,config=custom_oem_psm_config))
```

This should work but try passing the binarized image instead, tesseract works best with binarized images. Preprocessing is mandatory before passing the image to tesseract. Psm modes do not process the image.

Please correct me if I am wrong.